# how to add fixed transition-duration value on swiper sliders ''.swiper-wrapper" class?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

[i want to set a fixed transition-duration value on swiper-wrapper class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnORS.jpg)
its updating on slide-changes and when mousewheel start. is there any way to customize swiperJS and set a fix transition-duration value?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show the code and *not* an image - especially when its such a small amount!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this css class to your project:

```
.swiper-wrapper{
    transition-duration: 0ms !important;
}
```

this class will always override the style written on the swiper wrapper

Comment: Thank you!  You answered this question where many other stackoverflow answers did not.   Note for those wanting a very drawn out delay here would be a good value:     transition-duration: 1000ms !important;

Answer (score 0):

New **2023** solution:

You can just simply configure duration using **speed** property, like this:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  speed: 700, // 700 milliseconds
});
```